# How to use eve() in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, events, raphael

Can some one give me a simple example of Raphael `eve()`?

I don't quite understand the parameters and how to call events. 
I was searching around for a bit but seem like not so many people have used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example of the event functionality in [Raphaël](http://www.raphaeljs.com):

We define the function that will fire the event

```
function bar()
{
  var a, b;
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  eve("run-foo", "self", a, b);
}
```

The event listener function

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
  // if the event is fired from bar() :
  // this == "self"
  // arg1 == a == 1
  // arg2 == b == 2
  // arg3 == undefined/null
}
eve.on("run-foo", foo);
```

Comment: No worries! It took a while to figure out -- the documentation is a bit sparse in some areas.

Comment: also, namespaces are hierarchical, so `eve.on("asdf")` will be triggered by `eve("asdf.foo")`

Comment: @watson: If you tell us what's confusing, we might be able to help... :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsperf.com/eve-js-versus-events

Use [Event.js](http://www.events-js.com/). I think it is better. Not just faster. But understand the key conceptual difference. eve.js works without a DOM. Event.js is basicaly DOM events library. Although not 100%.