# Raphael - How create a custom event

Tags: events, raphael

As I wrote I'd like to write a custom event foa a Raphael's element, how can i do?
I just saw that `eve(name, scope, varargs)` but I didn't understand well, and if properly for creating a custom event.
I'd like understand how to create a my own custom event.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve. Its not very clear from your description. Maybe this will help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031901/how-to-use-eve-in-raphael

Comment: I don't know what other infoes put in the topic.